# webrtcstreamer No sound with audio

Tags: cocoapods-1.0.1

vue + webrtcstreamer, and rtsp``

`import { WebRtcStreamer } from '../compisition/webrtcstreamer'`
`import '../compisition/adapter.min'`
`player = new WebRtcStreamer('oneScreenVideo','http://192.168.xx.xx:8000')`
`player.connect(video.value.videoUrl)`

`Play video with VUE development without sound`